# How can I get date and time formats based on Culture Info?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I want is..
If culture is en-US then

```
string dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"; 
string timeFormat="24.00 hrs";
```

If culture is en-GB then

```
string dateFormat="dd/mmyyyy"; 
string timeFormat="24.00 hrs";
```

and so on for other countries..

Now how do I get these date and time format values ? What are the standards? Like which all countries use similar date/time formats and which ones don't ?

**ok I tried this :-**

```
 DateTime myDate = new DateTime();
   string us = myDate.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

string us gets value =1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Now how do I extract "dd/mm/yyyy" and "24.00 hrs" out of this...in my Dateformat column in my Table... I want to store STRINGS such as dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy NOT dates..In my TimeFormat column in the table, the values to be stores are STRINGS too, like I need to store either "24:00hrs" or "12:00hrs"

How do I do this now ?

**using ShorTimePattern returns these values as

```
h:mm tt and HH:mm
```

If I want to store the values in my DB exactly as "24:00hrs" and "12:00hrs", how do I use these values..h:mm tt and HH:mm
which one is for 24 hr format and which for 12 hr format ?**

**ok now there's another problem too...I want the information about Decimal Separator and Thousand Separator too based on the CultureInfo...whats the property for that ?**

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can retrieve the format strings from the `CultureInfo` `DateTimeFormat` property, which is a [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) instance. This in turn has properties like `ShortDatePattern` and `ShortTimePattern`, containing the format strings:

```
CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string shortUsDateFormatString = us.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
string shortUsTimeFormatString = us.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;

CultureInfo uk = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
string shortUkDateFormatString = uk.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
string shortUkTimeFormatString = uk.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
```

If you simply want to format the date/time using the `CultureInfo`, pass it in as your `IFormatter` when converting the `DateTime` to a string, using the [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576.aspx) method:

```
string us = myDate.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
string uk = myDate.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Comment: Could you please give link to some example or something ? never worked with IFormatter before..thnx

Comment: @Serenity - All `CultureInfo`s implement `IFormatter`. Answer updated with examples.

Comment: @Serenity - I believe that my first examples show you how to extract the format strings.

Comment: ok now there's another problem too...I want the information about Decimal Separator and Thousand Separator too based on the CultureInfo...whats the property for that ?

Comment: @serenity: Check out the MSDN docs on CultureInfo (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) - that structure also has a `NumberFormat` property that has what you're looking for

Comment: @Serenity - marc is simply frustrated with people who don't bother looking at the documentation. This acronym is actually used a lot all over the Internet. And he is right - you should look things up in the documentation first. Ask questions if you can't understand or find information.

Answer (score 34):

// Try this may help

```
string us = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

or

```
 string us = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Answer (score 5):

You could take a look at the [DateTimeFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat.aspx) property which contains the culture specific formats.

Answer (score 3):

Use a CultureInfo like this, from MSDN:

```
// Creates a CultureInfo for German in Germany.
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

// Displays dt, formatted using the CultureInfo
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString(ci));
```

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx). [Here](http://sharpertutorials.com/list-of-culture-codes/) is a link of all different cultures.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting a custom `CultureInfo` for `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture`:

```
Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = new Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);

customCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = customCulture;

DateTime newDate = System.Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Culture can be changed for a specific cell in grid view.

```
<%# DateTime.ParseExact(Eval("contractdate", "{0}"), "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) %>
```

For more detail check the link.

[Date Format Issue in Gridview binding with #eval()](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/899694/Date-Format-Issue-in-Gridview-binding-with-sharpev)