# datetimeoffset.datetime issues ?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

when I pass the datetimeoffset.datetime to a SQL server stored procedure, the result get the month and date wrong way around.

E.g when I pass 11/12/2012, the result became 12/11/2012. So 11th of December was changed to twelveth of November.

Is anything I can do to find the problem?

Comment: What is `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` set to? You likely have different culture settings for the c# runtime and SQL Server.

Comment: The datetimeoffset was select from the Calendar control on a machine in U.K. It then serialised into xml and transferred to an server in U.S to call the store procedure. What is the correct to way to make the format right? Shall I create a new datetime object  using the year, month and day property of the deserialized datetimeoffset object?

Comment: I think you should focus on xml. Check what value you get on deserialization.

Comment: The datetimeoffset was serialised and deserialized correctly. It only happens when pass the datetime property to stored procedure. T

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** it might be because of culture settings that you need to check in your C# code and SQL Server. In Europe and US the date formatting are quit different.

For example: us default date formatting is "mm/dd/yyyy", while EU is "dd/mm/yyyy"

Here is a post that directly address this culture settings in C# - [How can I get date and time formats based on Culture Info?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4353241/1437962)

Answer (score 0):

OK in your stored procedure you must use cast or covert to format it 
read this link about cast datetime type and formats 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: We are passing in the type of DateTime, not string.