# DateTime is not in proper format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a property as follows:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime ? EndDate { set; get; }
```

when I use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
```

I get a result as follows:

```
17.07.2013
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: +1 for "gimme teh codez plz...."

Comment: .NET DateTime formatting replaces the slashes with the date separator used by the current regional settings. Typically this will be the regional settings for the user that the asp.net application is running under.

Comment: I have been really bored at wr0K! and this hasnt been wr0king :`(

Comment: To change culture info when formatting dates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4353241/3713

Comment: Are you or your user using '.' as the date separator?

Comment: No I am not. But I am using `DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"` It should override whatever culture underlying there

Comment: No, it should not, it ends up in the same formatting routines as everything else, which replaces the slashes. The answer here is to make sure your application is running with the right culture information. Either hardcode it for everyone: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new ...`, or make it react to whoever is using the site.

Comment: ok Sir. Can you post that as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several ways to do this.

Either:

- Change the regional settings for the user running your web application
- Use the correct CultureInfo object when formatting
- Set the default CultureInfo object on the current thread
- Escape the slashes

To provide a CultureInfo object when formatting:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-US")))
```

To set the default CultureInfo object:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-US");
```

To escape the slashes, use single quotes:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}")]
```

Note that all the code ends up in [DateTime.ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) or one of its overloads, so that's the place to look for clues to this.