# create datetime irrespective of system date

Tags: c#-4.0

```
DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(localDate.Year, localDate.Month,
                           DateTime.DaysInMonth(localDate.Year, localDate.Month),
                           localDate.Hour, localDate.Minute, localDate.Second);
```

dt value is `31-08-2013 PM 06:45:00`

Because my system date format is in `PM 06:45 30-08-2013`.

I would like to get the value as `08-31-2013 18:45:00` in a variable of type `DateTime` **not of `string`** type.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590180/how-to-convert-a-datetime-string-to-a-current-culture-datetime-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797727/datetime-and-cultureinfo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353232/how-can-i-get-date-and-time-formats-based-on-culture-info

Comment: I think you just have a formatting problem here. See the various formatting options for .ToString() with the DateTime type. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: The value of a `DateTime` object is neither `31-08-2013 PM 06:45:00` nor `08-31-2013 18:45:00`, nor any other human-readable format. Internally the date is stored as a single long integer which represents the number of ticks since January 1st of the year 1. Any time you're looking at it as a date string it's because it's been converted to a string, for instance if you're looking at its value in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

The date/time is stored in a particular format regardless of the system locality.  Only the the output is affected by the locality.

Regardless of how it "looks" you can always change the output using the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method

And the various [formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc4ky857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can even [implement a global cultureinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576.aspx) to apply which may be what you're looking for