# Can I get the "YYYY-MM-DD" string in other languages?

Tags: c#

I need to show the "YYYY-MM-DD" as a template in a query editor, so the users know how to formate the dates. But because the application is multi-lingual, I thought it would be easier to understand if I'd display this string for each language.

So for German it would have to be: "JJJJ-MM-TT"

Is there a way to get these strings automatically in C#?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353232/how-can-i-get-date-and-time-formats-based-on-culture-info) will help you

Comment: True, congrats, anyway, i'am not sure if this is a real issue (no offense intended, that's still a  good question technically speaking), since YYYY-MM-DD is somewhat a convention amongst devs and peoples in general... Might be usefull to ask around before you jump into the development of such a solution as i don't think something similar exist (would be interested if it did indeed) :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get date and time formats based on Culture Info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353232/how-can-i-get-date-and-time-formats-based-on-culture-info)

Comment: I don't know of any built-in solution that will let you localize format strings. You'd have to implement a solution yourself. Once you have the respective mappings that shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Simple :             CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
            string format = info.DateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern;  Results for US is : yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'

Comment: If I understand correctly this is just a problem on how to show the format to the user in its own language not on how to change the formatting pattern used in code where everything stays as is. In that case you just need some kind of collection where you store the locale ID and the matching string to show to your users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe what you are asking is possible outside of the box, if you check [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#character-literals), you can see that only specific character literals are reserved for the DateTime formatter to be used when interpreting the string. Any other character literal will be included in the final DateTime string as is (assuming that your DateTime was successfully parsed).

You however can introduce extension functions to DateTime/String, that take CultureInfo and pretty much map a string like "JJJJ-MM-TT" to "YYYY-MM-DD", then pass the mapped string to the DateTime formatter.

You can try to provide custom DateTime formatters inside every different CultureInfo you support in your application, but still passing a string like "JJJJ-MM-TT" to the native DateTime formatter will not give you the desired result, without mapping it to the parse-able format.

If your question is just asking about how to show "JJJJ-MM-TT" to the user but still use "YYYY-MM-DD" when parsing the string, then you will just have to introduce a mapping of the different CultureInfo supported in your application and the strings you want to show to the user, then when presenting a query editor, you lookup the CultureInfo and get the desired string. Still there is no out of the box support for this.

Comment: I thought so, thanks for the comprehensive response.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, there's nothing built-in.

You will have to localize it manually, the same way you localize all the other strings in your application (e.g. by using resource files).