# how to change the date format in asp.net c# using JQuery dataicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, algorithm

I'm using the following code to get a date in a texfield. The wanted date format should be `dd/mm/yyyy`, but I keep getting `mm/dd/yyyy`. Any suggestions how to resolve this issue?

```
$(function () { 
  $('input[id$=fromTextField]').datepicker() 
});
```

Comment: I don't think that tags `c#`, `asp.net` and `algorithm` are applying to your question.

Comment: With regard to the tags, are you trying to set the format of the value shown in the UI, or how it's received on your server side?

Comment: any suggestion tags I up to change. I want to change the format to be used in the server @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: In which case there is no specific format of a DateTime value. You can output the format however you need. There are lots of resources around how to do this already, such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353232/how-can-i-get-date-and-time-formats-based-on-culture-info)

Comment: You can change date format like below and put this code in Jquery:

$('input[id$=fromTextField]' ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });

Comment: Please check my code and let me know

Comment: @Dilip no haven't worked unfortunately.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it did not change in the server side how to change how do I change the value in the ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code

```
$(function () { 
  $('#fromTextField').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-regional-dateformat:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
```

you want to get more details then please go this link:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: Please use "Code sample" formatting. This will make your answer more readable.