# Why date format changes for web application deployed on Azure ?(ASP .NET Core)

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

[Difference between Azure WebApp date format and the local App date format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhjKp.png)

I tried the query : "Alter database [MyDB] Collate french_ci_as" to change the database TIME_ZONE but
it doesn't  solve the problem.

I still have the format 'mm/dd/yyyy' on Azure WebApp. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you writing the date? The locale in which ASP.NET is running determines the format, unless you provide a specific CultureInfo and/or format.

Comment: I don't change the default CultureInfo. The date is a DateTime propertie in my ViewModel, on the view i use :  @Model.MyDate.

Comment: That's what I'm saying; the default CultureInfo is likely different between your local environment and the Azure environment. You have to specify the CultureInfo you wish to use (there's an overload to `ToString()` that takes an IFormatProvider).

Answer (score 0):

If you use .ToString method of DateTime class you can specify the formate.
Example
dateObject.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But the same code work fine locally, without using ToString("format").

Comment: It could be your local machine culture is different from the Azure App Service or VM culture.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353232/how-can-i-get-date-and-time-formats-based-on-culture-info

Answer (score 0):

Create two model values:

```
 public string date { get; set; }
 public string time { get; set; }
```

and this function:

```
public void DateandTimeofCalculation() {
    model.date = @DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    model.time = @DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");

}
```

So you can manipulate both date and time formats on both the development and Azure environment